# How to get data from Google analytics api for different websites

Tags: google-analytics, zend-framework2, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Google analytics api for different websites for example:

I have 67 websites and there record in Google analytics.

**Actually I want single website Top 10 links most visited, with numbers of times that link is visited and total website visits and search engine visits.**

I have **used GAPI** but **it doesn't show** for **specific website** :

```
    $ga = new gapi('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxx');
    $dimensions = array('browser','source','region');
    $metrics = array('pageViews','visitors','visits');
    $ga->requestReportData('12312123', $dimensions, $metrics, '-visits');
    $gaResults = $ga->getResults();
```

if you have answer for **Google analytics with zend framework2**,you can answer for this Question

Comment: -1 for last line... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16046559/949273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Solution My Own:

Account detail that cantain you websites:

```
$ga = new gapi('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxx');
```

give dimension and metrics that you want from google analytic

```
$dimensions = array('browser','source','region');
$metrics = array('pageViews','visitors','visits');
```

Each website in google analytics have a profile_id:123456
You can see it by login in to your account.

```
$ga->requestReportData(profile_id, $dimensions, $metrics, '-visits');
```

you will retrive data for specific website